# How to use WCF Message for writing Multiple Objects

Tags: wcf, message

I have this requirement, I have two classes Person and Department and i want to send object of these two classes in the System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message? How can i accomplish this. I there any best way alternative to that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you have to use a Message? Why not just create a DataContract that contains both objects?

Comment: I Could have done that. But i am using a already developed WCF service Which accepts and returns only messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Message class has a static method called CreateMessage which has an overload to take any object that can be serialized. 
Create a new datacontract\class with instances of Person and Department object. Pass the wrapper object to CreateMessage to serialize